# Create new table procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a procedure which adds / removes a table to the database. I'm working in SQL Server. The query works (it succeeds) but the table isn't added to the database.

I did refreshed...

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[upgrade_1]
as
begin
    create table awards (
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY,   
    name nvarchar(256) DEFAULT 'award',
    description nvarchar(256)
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    )
    /*update goto_vs
    set current_version = 1*/
end
```

Comment: Did you mean you executed the PROCEDURE and nothing happened? This will only create or modify the PROCEDURE, may be you need to execute it?

Comment: could you please post it as an answere? :D thank you.

Comment: Have a look at batches [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175502(v=sql.105).aspx?ppud=4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you have in the question will only modify the PROCEDURE. The procedure needs to be executed for it to perform the required task e.g. create the table

Execute the procedure with this statement

```
EXEC upgrade_1
```

That should create the table